# Ansible command fails with 'Failed to connect to the host via ssh' but succeeds after doing 'ansible all -m ping' - why?

Tags: ssh, ansible, ping

This is on an Ubuntu 16.10 Linux VM (host) going to an EC2 Ubuntu instance (client).

I do this command:

```
sudo ansible-playbook deploy.yml -vvv
```

And get:

```
fatal: [web1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.", "unreachable": true}
```

Yet if I do this immediately (seconds) afterward:

```
ansible all -m ping
```

The previous command works!

Is it something to do with `ControlPersist=60s`, like no more commands can be issued? Confusing.

Comment: Why do you use `sudo ansible-playbook` and `ansible` without `sudo`? This can use different credentials depending on your setup.

Comment: Strange. When I do `sudo ansible all -m ping`, it initially has the SSH error, but if I follow it with `ansible all -m ping`, the exact same command starts working seconds later. Thoroughly strange.

Comment: Do you know what is `sudo` for?

Comment: You're not understanding what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this may be a known Ansible bug where SSH connections intermittently fail, and give a poor error message. I'm on Ansible 2.1.1, the same version that so many people in this bug report are on too:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/15706

So upgrading Ansible would probably get around the error. Or use the workaround I discovered of pinging `ansible <your hosts> -m ping`.